# What is the Canadian-French expression literally translated as “grab some wood”?

Tags: expressions, québec

I've heard there's a phrase in Canadian-French meaning “take a seat” or “grab a chair” which literally translates as “to grab some wood”.

What's the phrase in French?

Answer (score 7):

In the good old times in Québec, when people would meet and listen to story tellers, Ikea chairs were not invented yet and anyone who would come and join in the merry circle would be invited to grab a log and sit on it. Hence the "tire-toi une bûche" in lieu of "please take a seat".

Comment: Je m'émerveille tous les jours du nombre de différences entre le Francais de France (ou de Belgique, ils sont quand-même assez similaires) et celui du Québec... D'ailleurs, existe-t-il un terme pour désigner ces expressions/mots typiques ? Un équivalent de "belgicisme" mais pour le Québec en somme...

Answer (score 3):

The expression is “*se tirer une [bûche](http://www.laparlure.com/recherche/?q=b%C3%BBche)*” in [Québec](http://www.lexilogos.com/quebecois_langue_dictionnaires.htm), literally “to pull oneself a log”. Most often seen with the imperative [form](http://www.conjugaison.com/conjuguer.php?verbe=se%20tirer&x=0&y=0):

> Tire-toi une bûche!

Not to be confused with “*prendre une [bûche](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-american/b%C3%BBche)*” which [means](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%BBche) (see second tab) “to fall down/fall flat” (on one's face) — generally “*tomber*”.